# beforeEnter in Vue routes does not work for children routes

Tags: vue.js, authentication, redirect, vue-router

I am using vue 2.6.10 and in my vue's router.js I set some routes like so

```
Vue.use(Router)

const router =  new Router({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'login',
      component: Login,
    },    

    {
      path: '/shoes',
      name: 'shoes',
      component: Shoes,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => { 
        if (store.state.login.quad_token == null) {
          next('/login');
        }
        next();
      },
      children:[
            {
              path: ':skateshoes',
              name: 'skateshoes',
              component: SkateShoes
            }, 
      //more children routes
```

The issue is that if I manually remove the cookie from my browser and got to `/shoes/skateshoes` I dont get redirected to the login page.

To get redirected, I have to edit the `skateshoes` children route like so

```
        {
          path: ':skateshoes',
          name: 'skateshoes',
          component: SkateShoes,
          beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => { 
            if (store.state.login.quad_token == null) {
              next('/login');
            }
            next();
          }
        },
```

I thought that putting `beforeEnter` in the parent will also work for all the children. Apparently this does not work , at least for me.

How do I make it work? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `beforeEach` guard instead of `beforeEnter`.

beforeEnter is a per route guard, it doesn't apply for children.

You can use [router's meta](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html) combine with `beforeEach` to add conditional logic.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I would also like your opinion for the same issue. What if I want to protect only `shoes` and its children? Replacing `beforeEnter` with `beforeEach` in my code as it is does not work. As I see it, I have to set `beforeEach` for all the routes, outside the `const router =  new Router({` obj. So in my case, should I keep the code with a `beforeEnter` for every route? Thanks

Comment: You can use route meta. You can check this https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html and https://scotch.io/tutorials/vue-authentication-and-route-handling-using-vue-router

Comment: Thanks again. One last thing. Just to be clear, in practice, there is no issue if I put `beforeEnter` to the routes and child-routes I want ?  Except maybe that I am repeating myself.

Comment: Yes, I think there is no particular issue with `beforeEnter`.

Answer (score 2):

yes it wouldn't work like that, because 'beforeEnter' guards is per-route guard.
If you want to use something global , then you can use beforeEach

Here you can read , how to implement it in your case : https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html

Hope, this could helps you :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. What if I want to protect only `shoes` and its children? Replacing `beforeEnter` with `beforeEach` in my code as it is does not work. As I see it, I have to set `beforeEach` for all the routes, outside the `const router =  new Router({` obj. So in my case, should I keep the code with a `beforeEnter` for every route? Thanks

Comment: I was ready to send you the same link as @ittus, who' already answered you :) ,